# Is It necessary to force SSL on the EC2 link to the production server?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, cloudflare

I have domain through GoDaddy and I use CloudFlare as my DNS, though which I have a SSL certificate. My hosting is on AWS.

When I go to the website through my domain name, SSL is enforced, and if I access through http, it's redirected to https - which is what I want.

However, when I access it through the EC2 domain, SSL isn't enforced, presumably because it's not on cloud flare's certificate.

My question is, is there a hazard to not keeping the EC2 domain to the production site enforced for SSL? I tried tracking the origin of my domain and it only goes back to CloudFlare, which forces SSL, so I would presume that it wouldn't be possible to track the site back to the EC2 domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent customers from bypassing Cloudflare and going directly to your website you need to redirect them back thru your domain name registered with Cloudflare. This will have the side effect of then enforcing HTTPS.

I am assuming:

- Cloudflare is terminating SSL and your webserver is only running HTTP.

Assuming that your web server is Apache there are several methods.

Use Server Alias redirects. Modify your VirtualHost entry like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAlias ec2-public-ipv4-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    redirect permanent / https://www.yoursite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

OR modify `.htaccess` in the root of your web server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ec2-public-ipv4-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Change the DNS name above to your actual EC2 Public DNS Name.

You will want to do the same thing if they hit your site using the Public IP address.

Add this rule to `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12\.34\.56\.789$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Replace the numbers above with your Public IP address. Keep the dots `.` in the IP address escaped with backslashes like the `\.`